# How to delete a elements in a array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I have an array in javascript.Example

```
var array=[1,2,3,4,5,2,6,7,2];
```

Ok, i want to delete value 2 in array. The result as

```
var array=[1,3,4,5,6,7];
```

Thank guys.

Comment: Look at splice and indexOf()... if you can create a new array then look at filter()

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** for that

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 2];

array = array.filter(function(v) {
  return v != 2
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Doesn't work - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w5LeyLuh/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny : updated , http://jsfiddle.net/w5LeyLuh/2/